# Chinese Remainder theorem clarification needed

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

> I'm trying to solve $p\equiv a\pmod{7}$ and $p\equiv b\pmod{4}$

$m_1=(4)^{-1} \pmod 7$

$m_2=(7)^{-1} \pmod 4$

I need to find $m_1'$ and $m_2'$ which I assumed to be the inverse of $m_1$ and $m_2$

Thus $4m_1\equiv 1 \pmod 7 \Rightarrow m_1'=2 $ and

$7m_2\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow m_2'=3 $

Putting everything together I get:

$a\times m_1'\times 4 + b\times m_2' \times 7 \pmod {28}$

$8a + 21b \pmod{28}$

Is it correct?

Comment: $\checkmark\,\!$

Comment: $8a + 21b = a \pmod 7$ and  $8a + 21b = b \pmod 4$